# MACRO definition both for a number and a string

Tags: c++

```
#define PI 3.1416
#define STRING(x) #x
#define STRING_PI STRING(PI)

void test()
{
    string sPI = STRING_PI;
    cout << sPI;
}
```

It outputs "PI" rather than 3.1416.

Comment: ok, you are right, it outputs `PI`. Do you have a question? If you have a problem with that macro the solution is to not use that macro btw

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Kox8Pv